# What is the fate of Densuke at the end of the last episode?

Tags: dennou-coil

In episode 23, Densuke is "lost" (mobbed my illegals) when he was protecting Yuuko (Okonogi) from illegals.

However, in the last episode, Yuuko and Kyouko both are able to see Densuke without their Dennou Eyeglasses. How is this possible (since Densuke only exists in the virtual space)? Does this mean he was reborn or is the meaning purely figurative?

[image: Is... he there?]

Comment: I think this is a question about interpretations and there's not going to be a definitive source, but I did not take his existence (digital or otherwise) literally in this scene. More like the classic ghost of a friend watching over them.

Answer (score 2):

To me the most rational answer to the fact of Densuke showing up at the very end, while both sisters are able to see him without actually having the glasses on. Is due to the fact they have a big connection to Densuke.

If you recall early on Yasako and Haraken discuss about how Illegals were born and they come down to the resolution they are born from emotions like love and anger.

So in resume my belief is that due to their deep love for Densuke, it creates his image at the very end, as something like a peace of mind as everything was resolved and that he was still there, in their hearts.